# how do i click drop down menu using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, sonarqube

i'm trying to upload some sonar ruleset files to multiple sonars.

i want to get help by web ui automator using Selenium.

i wrote some java code but it still doesn't work.

*added comment

bellowed code works on chrome driver but it doesn't work on safari driver.
please tell me how to modify code to work for multiple browser.

here is my code

```
public void openQualityProfiles() {
    String linkTextSettings = "Settings";
    String cssSelector = ".dropdown-menu > ul > li > a";
    WebElement settings = waitForElement(By.linkText(linkTextSettings));
    settings.click();
    WebElement qualityProfiles = waitForElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
    qualityProfiles.click();
}

public WebElement waitForElement(By locator) {
    WebElement target = null;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    target = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));

    return target;
}
```

and here is HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="showDropdownMenu('admin-panel'); return false;" class="link-more">Settings</a>
<div id="admin-panel" class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none">
<ul>
<li><a href="/profiles">Quality Profiles</a></li>

<li><a href="/settings/index">Configuration</a></li>
<li><a href="/users">Security</a></li>
<li><a href="/backup">System</a></li>
```

Comment: Please paste error log.I want to know what error you are facing in safari.Will you able to open drop-down.

Comment: There is no error on safari. My selenium code successfully clicked Settings menu and clicked Quality Profiles sub menu BUT safari didn't response on that action. just chrome does...

Answer (score 0):

If your submenu appears when mouse is over, you can use:

`new Actions(driver).moveToElement(yourMenu).build().perform();`

or try to click on

`driver.findElement(By.className("link-more")).click();`

Comment: I changed code like that.
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(qualityProfiles).build().perform(); 
but I got org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException Error.
Does Safari driver support mouseMoveTo action?

Comment: try this hack 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("admin-panel"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0]..style.display = 'block';", element);